# Need to restrict Max value from keyboard

Tags: angularjs, html

Below is the HTML code I am trying where I am able to restrict number which is greater that 5 by using up and down keys. but I need to restrict manual entry from keyboard. In current scenario, we can give any number through keyboard and it's accepting.

```
  <input type="number" max="5" min="1">
```

Comment: It accepting but It will show as error

Comment: It will accept but `form.$valid` will be false.

Answer (score 0):

**This piece of code replace entered number with max number which shows max number(if entered number is greater than max number)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">

        <h4> Prevent typing value greater than max (i.e 100):
        <input type="number" min="1" max="100" limit-to-max />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller("controller", function($scope) {

        });

        app.directive("limitToMax", function() {
            return {
                link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
                    element.on("keydown keyup", function(e) {
                        if (Number(element.val()) > Number(attributes.max) &&
                            e.keyCode != 46 // delete
                            &&
                            e.keyCode != 8 // backspace
                        ) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            element.val(attributes.max);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```